# Is there an easy way to predict whether a given element will crystallise in the FCC or in the HCP structure?

Tags: condensed-matter, group-theory, crystals, metals

I noticed, reading the solid state physics book by Ibach & Lüth, that the majority of elements  crystallize in a handful of space groups:

[image]

I highlighted face-centered cubic (FCC) structures in blue and hexagonal closely-packed (HCP) structures in green.

As I understand it, directed covalent bonds give rise to the more intricate structures in the p-block, for instance the diamond structures in red.

Then, metallic bonds are more isotropic and spread, thus favouring closely packed structures / high coordination numbers. If the orbitals have enough overlap with the next-to-next neighbour, this can also favour body-centered cubic structures (orange), that have a high effective coordination number. On the other hand, if the orbitals overlap mostly with those of the next neighbours, close packings (FCC and HCP) are favoured.

[image]

Now to my question: is there a heuristic way to understand why an element would select HCP over FCC, or vice-versa ? Both have the same coordination number and packing fraction. Why would a particular stacking of planes be selected (ABAB or ABCABC), and not some random mixture of the two ?

Comment: Not particularly. Just to make it more confusing you are focused on the crystal structures at room temperature - many of the elements change crystal structure with temperature.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/57484/why-alkali-metals-have-bcc-structure/57599#57599 may help illuminate some of the difficulties (full disclosure: my answer). https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/15697/is-there-a-systematic-way-to-determine-the-expected-cubic-structure-of-metals/15848#15848 may also help (also one of my answers)

Comment: Fair enough, but this could still be incorporated if we understand the effect of temperature on the (hypothetical) property that controls FCC vs HCP.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look it up !